# Registration Form Type

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to modify my registration form to include a type (Restaurant or Consumer). I need a checkbox that once checked will indicate the account should be a Restaurant. (Not checked = Consumer).

I've researched Gates but it's not exactly what i'm looking for. My thought process was to make a boolean attribute in the user migration.

seeder

```
public function run() {
    DB::table('users')->insert([
    'name' => "admin",
    'email' => 'admin@test.com',
    'password' => bcrypt('admin'),
    // 'type' => true
    ]);
}
```

migration

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        // $table->boolean('type');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Upon the user checking the box, i want the restaurant users to be able to edit certain properties. With the consumer having no permissions, only viewing rights.

Comment: I would make an enum column for this, and then set up policies based on it

Comment: I would create two tables Users and Restaurants for this and take advantage of the eloquent relationships

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this
**Schema**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->boolean('type')->default(0);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Then you can run the **migration**:

```
public function run() {
    DB::table('users')->insert([
    'name' => "admin",
    'email' => 'admin@test.com',
    'password' => bcrypt('admin'),
    'type' => 1
    ]);
}
```